# Sponsorships on CV

Tags: resume

I've received a sponsorship from a company to pursue initiatives for a club that I co-founded. Should I list this on my CV?

If so, how should I go about describing it on a CV - are funding amounts typically listed?

Comment: Are you still a student? Or a recent graduate? Was it because of your efforts that you received that sponsorship? If you put it on your resume, you better be prepared to talk about it in detail and how it highlights your contributions. And if you're applying for a fundraising position or a sales job, putting that down might be worthwhile for you. But for other types of jobs, it really depends. We can't make that determination for you. We don't know the story beyond the sponsorship. We don't know what the rest of your resume looks like, nor what type of job you're actually applying for.

Comment: I'm still a student and the sponsorship was directly tied to my efforts to acquire it

Comment: Then put it down. But again, I'm saying this only knowing a tiny fraction of your story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the initiatives were successful, and the club in question isn't malicious/illegal in nature, then sure.

On placing it on your resume, simply place summarized info. 
Something like

```
Founded Club Y
- An organization focused on (the clubs goals)
- (other strong points/accomplishments of the club)
- (maybe the total members of the club as of today
- Received sponsorship from companyX for spearheading/founding club Y
```

As stated in @Stephan Branczyk's comments, be prepared to discuss in detail when the interviewer asks about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm planning on listing the club under extracurriculars. Would you add the sponsorship as a line within this listing (as done here) or use a separate listing under "Achievements"?

Comment: Well, for me I'd place the club's name under achievements. Because you founded it. Keep the sponsorship details beneath it.